# what's some good fonts for dual arabic and english use in linux debian?

Tags: linux, debian, fonts, deepin

I've installed google fonts but found it a hard to choose a good font for dual language .. each font may good in a language and bad in the other, I included a screen shot, Arabic texts are weirdly displayed.

[image]

so what a good font that is displayed well on the two languages texts?
and what's the "Standard font" and "Mono spaced fonts" means, it's the way to choose fonts in my deepin distro?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm why don't you try the **Ubuntu font**, with the *normal variation* and *normal weight*. It should be working fine I suppose (and also because I've used it in the past)...

=> [Click here to get it](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Ubuntu)

Comment: @MohamedIbrahim Did it work?

Comment: No it appears weird too